# Views3 - Is there are feature in Views3 that allows for authenticated users to change the fields in a view?

Tags: views

I'm using Drupal 7 to display a particular content type as a table view. This particular content type has the possibility of 15 columns, but I want to give users the option of displaying fields that are interesting to them. Does Views3 allow for users to select which fields he or she is interested in and save that to the profile?

Drupal 6 has a module based on Views - Control field display, which seems to have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

you can allow users acces to the views UI but you couldn't limit that just to "fields". It wouldn't be end user friendly either.

You might want to show all fields in your view and then hide the fields dynamically with css.

If you want it more robust you can use a hook like [hook_views_post_execute](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_post_execute/7) to remove fields dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Field permissions. You can fine grained decide which fields you want to display to a specific role.

You can give permission to let users edit the permissions for fields. It is off course not designed for exactly what you want. But it can be a good starting point to think about.

http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

There is also flags and rules modules that can be used to achieve such a functionality.